# How to redirect domain.com/admins to www.domain.com/admins?

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect

How to  redirect from domain.com/admins to www.domain.com/admins . I have tried editing .htaccess file but its not working . I have searched the internet but they have code for only domain.com to www.domain.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^admins/?$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

That rule is only for `/admins` URI. If you want to do this for **all the URIs** then use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```